# Why do I get "CS8618: Non-nullable property must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor" on a string property?

Tags: string, reference-type, c#-11.0

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that strings are, and always have been, a reference type in C#. And if this is still true in C# 11, why do I get `CS8618:  Non-nullable property must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor` on the following code:

```
public partial class MyClass : SomeOtherClass {
    // Generates CS8618
    private string _userInitials { get; set; } 
}
```

I've been searching SO and Google for an hour but can't seem to find any logical reason for this. MTIA :-)

Comment: Strings ARE a reference type, which means they can be null.  Without a constructor, your string property will be initialized to null.  Unless the parameter is declared nullable (that is, `private string? _userInitials`), that's not allowed.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts! When was this compiler warning introduced? I've been working with C# for over 10 years, but never for companies that cared about being on the latest language version. So I guess I've probably been doing things "wrong" for a long time, and never realised it until now lol.

Comment: I guess the main reason why I'm confused is that I've always thought of the ? operator as saying "hey C#, I want this thing to be nullable!", but strings are *implicitly* nullable, so I don't get why I'm needing to add ? to all my strings all of a sudden. This is a nuisance IMO.

Comment: It is a relatively recent change:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies

Comment: Cool, thanks again mate! Feel free to post a full answer if you want the rep and I'll gladly accept it :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings ARE a reference type, which means they can be null. Without a constructor, your string property will be initialized to null. Unless the parameter is declared nullable (that is, `private string? _userInitials`), that's not allowed.

They have only recently changed things so having null in a reference type is not allowed unless it declared nullable:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies